# update multiple rows in the table

Tags: php

that must be easy but it is simply to late for me, i have a table with 3 columns

1. Product
2. Price
3. Week

Fro example:

Product   Price   Week 
Rice             1,5         36  
 
Peanuts   2,5         36  
Bread          0,5          36  
Rice             1,2         37  
Peanuts    2,6         37  
Bread          0,8         37

How can I update the table to copy the price for one product from one week to another.
Let say I want to copy the prices from the week 37 to week 38 since they are staying the same.

Comment: You might want to consider reading about [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: Are you looking for a SQL solution (in which case, which version of SQL), or a solution for a table held in a PHP array?

Comment: Why fill your database with so much redundant data? Instead, if you want the price for a week, say, 35, you can just do a SELECT * FROM table WHERE Week <= 35 ORDER BY Week DESC LIMIT 1. That way, if there have been no price changes since week e.g. 29, you'll just get the row and price for week 29.

Answer (score 0):

You can just grab the result from the week you want to copy and insert it into the table like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (product, price, week)
SELECT product, price, '[NEW WEEK VALUE]'
FROM table WHERE week = '[OLD WEEK VALUE]'
```

Whether not you use quotes around the week values would depend on whether the column is integer or text type of column.

To update an existing row with value from other you could use the REPLACE syntax like this:

```
REPLACE INTO table (product, price, week)
SELECT product, price, '[NEW WEEK VALUE]'
FROM table WHERE week = '[OLD WEEK VALUE]'
```

Note however that it you don't have a primary key or unique index on the combination of product and week columns, this will simply add another row.  You should like have a unique index or primary key on these columns anyway if you want to enforce one product entry per week.  Also note that this will act as an insert if the existing product/week combination doe not yet exist, so this is a versatile approach to updating/adding this data is it is not know whether that product/week combination yet exists.

Comment: There's no mention of SQL in the OP's question. Additionally, this wouldn't work for MySQL.

Comment: There is mention of a table and php. Use of sql to insert data from PHP into a database seems legit.

Comment: @MikeW THere is a database that he is interacting with in PHP, it is clear that he needs to write SQL to interact with that database.

Comment: actually I do not think I could use INSERT INTO since I have all the data already I would just need to add (update) the price.

Comment: @user2615859 Your example seems to indicate that you have a record for each week.  You cannot add a new row without performing an INSERT.  If you are just trying to update an existing row than a simply UPDATE will work however this will not "copy" the data into a new row as your question suggests.

Comment: yes i do have a record for each week, and for week 38 as well, I only need to update the price to be the same as in week 37. I need update and not creation of new rows.

Comment: @user2615859 OK Your example did not show a week 38 value so it seemed as if an insert is what you want.  I have updated my answer to also show the use of `REPLACE INTO` which would do what you want and actually provide a more flexible approach that would work whether or not that existing product/week record exists of not.